# ARM gcc inline assembler optimization problem

Tags: arm, assembly

Why is it that my inline assembler routine is not working when I have optimization flag -O3 but it works with other optimization flags (-O0, -O1, -O2, -Os)?

I even added volatile to all my assembler instructions, which I thought would tell the compiler to not touch or reorder anything?

Best Regards

Mr Gigu

Comment: Define "not working". What did you expect it to do and what happened instead? What is the routine doing? How do you call it? Can you post the source? Did you look at the disassembly of the produced binary?

Comment: After revisiting my question 2 years later, I realise how absurd my question was with very little information. That makes it more impressive that FrankH manage to answer my question. The problem was that I did not specify any clobber list in my inline assembler which destroyed the register values. Reason that worked with certain optimizations were probably fluke coincidence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC inline assembler is very sensitive towards correct specification.

In particular, **you have to be extremely precise about specifying the correct constraints** to make sure the compiler does not decide to "optimize" your assembler code. There's a few things to watch out for. Take an example.

The following two:

```
    int myasmfunc(int arg)    /* definitely buggy ... */
    {
        register int myval asm("r2") = arg;

        asm ("add r1, r0, #22\n" ::: "r1");
        asm ("adds r0, r1, r0\n" ::: "r0", "cc");
        asm ("subeq r2, #123\n" ::: "r2");
        asm ("subne r2, #213\n" ::: "r2");
        return myval;
    }
```

and

```
    int myasmfunc(int arg)
    {
        int myval = arg, plus = arg;

        asm ("add %0, #22\n\t" : "+r"(plus));
        asm ("adds %1, %2\n\t"
             "subeq %0, #123\n\t"
             "subne %0, #213\n\t" : "+r"(myval), "+r"(plus) : "r"(arg) : "cc");
        return myval;
    }
```

might look similar at first sight and you'd naively assume they do the same; but they are very far from that !

There are multiple problems with the first version of this code.

1. For one, if you specify it as separate `asm()` statements, the compiler is free to *insert* arbitrary code in-between. That in particular means the `sub` instructions, even though they themselves don't *modify* the condition codes, can fall foul of things the compiler choose to insert which did.
2. Second, again due to the split of the instructions when specifying separate `asm()` statements, there's no guarantee the code generator will choose the same register to put `myval` in both times, the `asm("r2")` spec in the variable declaration notwithstanding.
3. Third, the assumption made in the first that `r0` contains the argument of the function is wrong; the compiler, by the time it gets to the assembly block, might've choosen to move this argument to whatever other place. Worse even since again you have the split statement, and no guarantee is made as to what happens *between* two `asm()`. Even if you specify `__asm__ __volatile__(...);` the compiler treats *two* such blocks as independent entities.
4. Fourth, you're not telling the compiler that you're clobbering / assigning `myval`. It might've chosen to temporarily move it elsewhere because you're clobbering "r2" and when returning, decide to restore it from ... (???).

Just for the fun of it, here's the output of the first function, for the following four cases:

1. default - `gcc -c tst.c`
2. optimized - `gcc -O8 -c tst.c`
3. using some unusual options - `gcc -c -finstrument-functions tst.c`
4. that plus optimization - `gcc -c -O8 -finstrument-functions tst.c`

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 :
   0:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0  ; 0x0
   8:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12 ; 0xc
   c:   e50b0008    str r0, [fp, #-8]
  10:   e51b2008    ldr r2, [fp, #-8]
  14:   e2811016    add r1, r1, #22 ; 0x16
  18:   e0910000    adds    r0, r1, r0
  1c:   0242207b    subeq   r2, r2, #123    ; 0x7b
  20:   124220d5    subne   r2, r2, #213    ; 0xd5
  24:   e1a03002    mov r3, r2
  28:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  2c:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0  ; 0x0
  30:   e8bd0800    pop {fp}
  34:   e12fff1e    bx  lr


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 :
   0:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
   4:   e2811016    add r1, r1, #22 ; 0x16
   8:   e0910000    adds    r0, r1, r0
   c:   0242207b    subeq   r2, r2, #123    ; 0x7b
  10:   124220d5    subne   r2, r2, #213    ; 0xd5
  14:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 :
   0:   e92d4830    push    {r4, r5, fp, lr}
   4:   e28db00c    add fp, sp, #12 ; 0xc
   8:   e24dd008    sub sp, sp, #8  ; 0x8
   c:   e1a0500e    mov r5, lr
  10:   e50b0010    str r0, [fp, #-16]
  14:   e59f0038    ldr r0, [pc, #56]   ; 54 
  18:   e1a01005    mov r1, r5
  1c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 
  20:   e51b2010    ldr r2, [fp, #-16]
  24:   e2811016    add r1, r1, #22 ; 0x16
  28:   e0910000    adds    r0, r1, r0
  2c:   0242207b    subeq   r2, r2, #123    ; 0x7b
  30:   124220d5    subne   r2, r2, #213    ; 0xd5
  34:   e1a04002    mov r4, r2
  38:   e59f0014    ldr r0, [pc, #20]   ; 54 
  3c:   e1a01005    mov r1, r5
  40:   ebfffffe    bl  0 
  44:   e1a03004    mov r3, r4
  48:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  4c:   e24bd00c    sub sp, fp, #12 ; 0xc
  50:   e8bd8830    pop {r4, r5, fp, pc}
  54:   00000000    .word   0x00000000


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 :
   0:   e92d4070    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
   4:   e1a0100e    mov r1, lr
   8:   e1a05000    mov r5, r0
   c:   e59f0028    ldr r0, [pc, #40]   ; 3c 
  10:   e1a0400e    mov r4, lr
  14:   ebfffffe    bl  0 
  18:   e2811016    add r1, r1, #22 ; 0x16
  1c:   e0910000    adds    r0, r1, r0
  20:   0242207b    subeq   r2, r2, #123    ; 0x7b
  24:   124220d5    subne   r2, r2, #213    ; 0xd5
  28:   e59f000c    ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; 3c 
  2c:   e1a01004    mov r1, r4
  30:   ebfffffe    bl  0 
  34:   e1a00005    mov r0, r5
  38:   e8bd8070    pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
  3c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

As you can see, *neither* of these does what you'd be hoping to see; the second version of the code, though, on `gcc -c -O8 ...` ends up as:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 :
   0:   e1a03000    mov r3, r0
   4:   e2833016    add r3, r3, #22 ; 0x16
   8:   e0933000    adds    r3, r3, r0
   c:   0240007b    subeq   r0, r0, #123    ; 0x7b
  10:   124000d5    subne   r0, r0, #213    ; 0xd5
  14:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

and that is, rather closely, what you've specified in your assembly and what you're expecting.

Morale: Be explicit and exact with your constraints, your operand assignments, and keep interdependent lines of assembly within *the same* `asm()` block (make a multiline statement).

Answer (score 1):

This really should be a comment, but I'm unable to post one for some reason :(

The compiler optimization shouldn't really mess with your assembly. So, as Igor said, in what way is this "not working"? Maybe your ASM branches into a function, which has been optimized by the compiler giving a different result to what your assembly code might depend on?

some source file or more info about the compiler might be useful

Comment: Newbies can't comment.  :-)  You need 50 points first. I'll give you 10 with a totally unfounded upvote.

Comment: in `gcc`, the compiler optimization _will_ mess with your inline assembly in _very significant_ ways unless you're extremely careful what you ask for. That's understandably a gripe to many, but it's by design/intent and unlikely to change.

Comment: @FrankH - Oh, wasn't aware GCC would muck about with inline assembly too, apologies